# KeyError: '[ ...... ] not in index'

Tags: python, indexing, keyerror

I am doing standardization of my dataset

```
def standardization(new_df2, labelcol):
    from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
    labels = new_df2[labelcol]
    del new_df2[labelcol]
    scaled_features = StandardScaler().fit_transform(new_df2.values)
    new_df3 = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features, index = new_df2, columns = 
       new_df2.columns)
    new_df3[labelcol] = labels

    return new_df3

    labelcol = new_df2.population     #population is one of the columns in dataframe
    new_df3 = standardization(new_df2, labelcol)
    print(new_df3)
```

I receive the following error!

```
KeyError: '[  322.  2401.   496. ...,  1007.   741.  1387.] not in index'
```

As far I've seen, `322, 2401, ...` are the values in the `population`  column.

Please help me how to get rid of this error. What is this implying?

P.S: `new_df2` = `(20640, 14)` and `labelcol.shape` = `(20640,)`

Comment: Can you please properly indent your code? Python relies heavily on code indentation, and this may well be your error.

Comment: I have edited the post above. Sorry, it was just here I didn't indent properly. The Keyerror is there no matter.

Comment: what is the type of `[  322.  2401.   496. ...,  1007.   741.  1387.]`? Is it a list?

Comment: Yes, it is a list

Answer (score 4):

The following code got my question solved

```
def standardization(new_df2, labelcol):

    dflabel = new_df2[[labelcol]]
    std_df = new_df2.drop(labelcol, 1)
    scaled_features = StandardScaler().fit_transform(std_df.values)
    new_df3 = pd.DataFrame(scaled_features, columns = std_df.columns)
    new_df3 = pd.concat([dflabel, new_df3], axis=1)

    return new_df3
```

Thanks for those who tried helping.